# Why can't I seem to reconcile constants in my Surface Integral Formula?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I was trying to re-derive the surface integral formula from scratch and I came to a problem involving constants.

I begin by considering a point A: $(x,y,z(x,y))$ and an infinitesmal change in the x and y direction given as points B: $(x + \Delta x, y z(x + \Delta x,y))$ and $C: (x, y+\Delta y, z(x,y+\Delta y))$. If I compute the area of the triangle by these points as a function of $x,y$ and $z(x,y)$ times $\Delta x, \Delta y$ then taking a sum over all such areas as the two $\Delta$ quantities goes to 0, should yield me the surface integral.

Now by Taylor's theorem for sufficiently small $\Delta x, \Delta y$, 
$$z(x + \Delta x, y) = z(x,y) + \Delta x \frac{\partial z}{\partial x}$$
$$z(x , y + \Delta y) = z(x,y ) + \Delta y \frac{\partial z}{\partial y}$$

So now if consider the area spanned between these points, that area is given by $$\frac{1}{2} || (B-A) \times (C-A)||$$

$$B-A = \left( \Delta x, 0, \Delta x \frac{\partial z}{\partial x} \right)$$
$$C-A = \left( 0, \Delta y, \Delta y \frac{\partial z}{\partial y} \right)$$

So their cross product is

$$ \Delta x \Delta y \left(- \frac{\partial z}{\partial x}, - \frac{\partial z}{\partial y}, 1 \right) $$

So then the areas of the triangle are:

$$ \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{1 +\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}^2 +  \frac{\partial z}{\partial y}^2} \Delta x \Delta y$$

Thus the surface area of $z(x,y)$ around a region should be

$$ \iint_{\text{region}} \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{1 +\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}^2 +  \frac{\partial z}{\partial y}^2} dx dy $$

But the actual surfacae integral is:

$$ \iint_{\text{region}}  \sqrt{1 +\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}^2 +  \frac{\partial z}{\partial y}^2} dx dy $$

So where did I go wrong?

Comment: The ${1\over2}$ is used if you're finding the area of a triangle. The area of the parallelogram is just $\|(B-A)\times (C-A)\|$.

Comment: So how do I know that infinitesmal parallelograms are more correct than infinitesmal triangles. It's not clear since both will become small and do tesselate the entire surface.

Comment: @frogeyedpeas Maybe if you wrote out the sum (and specified the tessellation) and compared it to the Riemann sum, say, before jumping to the integral, the answer would appear...

Comment: @frogeyedpeas Triangles only tesselate half a plane $$\begin{align}\blacktriangle\blacktriangle~~& \\[-2ex]\blacktriangle\blacktriangle\blacktriangle&\end{align}$$

Comment: You're taking the $(x,y)$ region and dividing it up into rectangles: you're cutting apart the surface by slicing it with planes of the form $x=k$ and $y=k$. If the function $z(x,y)$ does not vary too much, you will cut the surface into quadrilaterals by doing this.